# Visual Studio 2013 "Add View" dialog takes a long time to load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dialog

In VS 2013, when I right click the solution explorer and go to `Add > View...` the whole IDE locks up for a very long time - approximately **20 seconds**. After this time period, the "Add View" dialog finally appears and everything returns to normal.

1. **Why does this happen?** It's such a simple dialog. All I want to do is
   add an empty view, which is, essentially, an empty text file.
2. **How can I speed it up?**

n.b. It's worth noting that I have a pretty quick computer with a fast SSD. Most operations in VS are very, very quick - it's just this dialog.

Comment: Lucky you, I can go and use the bathroom while I wait for this dialog to load. No idea what the issue is, but it didn't start happening until we upgraded our projects to .NET 4.5 and MVC5(from .NET 4 and MVC4).

Comment: I confirm this issue. After upgrading to .NET 4.5 and MVC 5 Add View dialog stopped working. I tried to wait more than 10 minutes several times, but Visual Studio 2013 is not clickable. Cursor has shape of text selector and VS acts like its an image instead of application. It does not hang, but nothing is happening when I click it. Only way now to add a View is to create it manually. Otherwise only restarting VS brings it back to its normal state. **Extremely annoying bug**.

Comment: This is still happening in VS2015 (and I'm assuming 2017, but I haven't used that much yet)... why hasn't this been addressed yet? It is super annoying having to wait 5-10 minutes for a dialog to appear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the things that opening that dialog does is it looks for an Entity Framework model and uses those entities to populate the dialog with auto creation templates (to create shell pages for CRUDL type operations) on an entity type.  To do this it seems to do a sort of in-memory build (i.e. it doesn't seem to output anything to the file system).  I have found in the past that if you don't have a particularly simple entity model it has a hard time; in an earlier version if your entity context did not have a parameterless constructor it would fail outright.

I have only used the `Add > View` dialog for making the list views and such for entities.  For everything else I use the `Add > MVC 5 View Page (Razor)`.  it doesn't connect to your entities, or do anything beyond adding a cshtml page to your Solution Explorer.

Comment: As 2013 is pretty old now I'm going to give you this as nobody has actually found a way to stop it taking ages (I'm assuming there isn't a way). However you've provided a workaround as well as explaining why it happens.

Comment: Note that the *MVC 5 View Page (Razor)* option automatically upgrades the MVC libraries by installing/upgrading NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around, I tend to copy and paste and existing view and then trim as required. Rubbish I know, but so much faster. The the slowness has been an issue for years!